# Modifying the Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, improper-integrals, special-functions, poisson-distribution

*The Poisson Distribution* $Pr(M|\lambda)$ is given by $$Pr(M|\lambda) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^M}{M!}~~~~M = 0,1,2...$$ with mean $\lambda$. In addition, the distribution has the property that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} Pr(M|\lambda) d \lambda = 1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*)$$ as is proved in [the post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312870/does-the-likelihood-function-for-the-poisson-distribution-integrate-to-1). I am interested in adapating this Poisson Distribution so that it can include an additional parameter (say $\mu$) which determines the width of the distribution (much like the *variance* does for the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)). Does anyone have any ideas of how this can be achieved while still maintaining that property $(*)$ holds?

Note I want to specifically work with the poisson distrbution rather than the normal distribution due to how the shape of the poisson distribution at zero.

Comment: I think it should be possible with the change $\lambda\rightarrow\lambda\mu$ being $\mu$ an arbitrary parameter.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for your response but I don't see how that would allow you to independently manipulate the width of the Poisson distribution. That's just changing the mean of the Poisson, hence effectively just shifting it either left or right. It would still have the same fixed profile which all Poisson distributions have.

Comment: The problem is that, for the Poisson distribution, you have the mean that is equal to the variance, $\lambda$, and so, you will have hard times to get a proper way to satisfy your requirements. With a second parameter, you will able to modulate the variance at expenses of a varying mean.

Comment: @Jon I'm still not seeing how the second parameter adds anything..."With a second parameter, you will able to modulate the variance at expenses of a varying mean"-But this occurs even without changing $\lambda$ to variable $\lambda \mu$?

Comment: @Jon What do you think of my above query? Thanks for your time.

Comment: The Poisson distribution is defined by limiting case of the binomial distribution as $N\rightarrow\infty$ and $p\rightarrow0$ such that $Np\rightarrow\lambda$. You are interested in a different distribution: apart from having at least two parameters, what other properties should it have? In principle you should be able to make up anything. You could consider an ensemble of Poisson distributions having a distribution of $\lambda$ for example.

Comment: What do you mean by the "width" of the distribution? Variance or something else?

Comment: @Dean Thanks for your response. Other than the property which allows two parameters (one of which denotes the mean and the other which controls the sharpness (width) of the distribution about the mean) I want the distribution to satisfy the condition $(*)$ above. Do you have any idea how such a distribution can be constructed?

Comment: @gg The Poisson distribution does not allow you to control the narrowness of the distribution as the normal distribution does, in that sense I want to modify the Poisson distribution so as to allow a second parameter to do this (in a similar way that the variance does for the normal distribution). As noted in the comment above, the variance and mean are the same parameter for a Poisson distribution hence I think I have to modify the distribution to achieve this.

Comment: Yes I understand but how do you define "width" or "narrowness" for a distribution? If I gave you two distributions on $\mathbb{N}$ with the same mean, how do you decide if one is more "narrow" or has less or more width than the other? And are there any other requirements in addition to (*)? How about if it had finite support for example?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following construction:

Let $U\sim \mathcal{U}[a,b]$ and $N\sim \text{Poisson}(U)$.

Through easy calculations we can see that:

1) $\mathbb{E}(N\mid U)\sim \mathcal{U}[a,b]$

2) $\text{Var}(N\mid U)\sim \mathcal{U}[a,b]$

Now, we can calculate

$\mathbb{E}(N)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(N\mid U))=\mathbb{E}(\text{`}\mathcal{U}[a,b]\text{´})=\dfrac{a+b}{2}$, and

$\text{Var}(N)=\text{Var}(\mathbb{E}(N\mid U))+\mathbb{E}(\text{Var}(N\mid U))=\text{Var}(\text{`}\mathcal{U}[a,b]\text{´})+\mathbb{E}(\text{`}\mathcal{U}[a,b]\text{´})=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}+\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Now, suppose that you want a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. With the previous construct, you must find $a,b$ such that:

- $\mu=\frac{a+b}{2}$
- $\sigma^2=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}+\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}+\mu$

For solve this system, calculate:

- $b+a=2\mu$
- $b-a=\sqrt{12(\sigma^2-\mu)}$

And then:

- $b=\frac{2\mu+\sqrt{12(\sigma^2-\mu)}}{2}$
- $a=\frac{2\mu-\sqrt{12(\sigma^2-\mu)}}{2}$

Obs: this construction works if $\sigma^2\geq\mu$, but if you must that the random variable comports as Poisson, this is essential.

Comment: Similarly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture